# Something about the python Regular Expression

Tags: python

Recently,I have read an article about data science.There is one point make me confused.It is a use of 'x.group()'.I still can't understand it.I will show it in the picture below.
And the code is like this:

```
import re
negations_dic = {"isn't":"is not", "aren't":"are not", "wasn't":"was not", "weren't":"were not"}
lower_case = "I isn't a sds"
neg_pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(negations_dic.keys()) + r')\b')
neg_handled = neg_pattern.sub(lambda x: negations_dic[x.group()], lower_case)
print(neg_handled)
```

And this is the picture [picture about the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/895Ws.jpg).Hope someone can help me.

Comment: I have tried to put 0、1、2 into the x.group(),and I don't know why x.group(0) and x.group(1) return the same result.x.group(2) return an error is resonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **The `lambda` function**

Lambda function is just a way to define a function inside an expression. You could replace your code with the following one, with a classic function and without lambda (and so without 'x' in your code):

```
import re

def func(m):
    return negations_dic[m.group()]

negations_dic = {"isn't":"is not", "aren't":"are not", "wasn't":"was not", "weren't":"were not"}
lower_case = "I isn't a sds"
neg_pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(negations_dic.keys()) + r')\b')
neg_handled = neg_pattern.sub(func, lower_case)

print(neg_handled)
```

2. **The `sub()` method**

Here is an extract of Python documentation regarding `sub()` method:

> **sub(repl, string)**
>   Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl.  [...] 
>   If repl is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping
>   occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object
>   argument, and returns the replacement string.

In your code, the argument `repl` is a function: it will replace each match object captured by the regex with its corresponding value in the dictionary `negations_dic`.

3. **The `match.group()`method**

Here is an extract of Python documentation regarding `match.group()` method:

> **match.group([group1, ...])**
>   Returns one or more subgroups of the match.
>   If there is a single argument, the result is a single string [...]
>   Without arguments, group1 defaults to zero (the whole match is returned).
>   If a groupN argument is zero, the corresponding return value is the entire matching string; if it is in the inclusive range [1..99], it is the string matching the corresponding parenthesized group.

This explains your result, i.e.:

- `x.group()` is equivalent to `x.group(0)`
- `x.group(0)` returns the whole match: `is'nt`
- `x.group(1)` returns the string matching the 1st parenthesized group: `is'nt`
- `x.group(2)` returns an error because there is no 2nd parenthesized group.

Moreover here is an example using `re.search` for better understanding of the way `group()`is working:

```
import re

m = re.search(r'((2nd) and (3rd) group)', '2nd and 3rd group')

print(m.group())  # it prints "2nd and 3rd group"
print(m.group(0)) # it prints "2nd and 3rd group"
print(m.group(1)) # it prints "2nd and 3rd group"
print(m.group(2)) # it prints "2nd"
print(m.group(3)) # it prints "3rd"
print(m.group(4)) # it returns an error `IndexError: no such group` because there is no 4th group
```

4. **You should read and learn more about `re` and lambda functions in Python.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer,it is really helpful.But I am still a little confused about the 1st parenthesized group.If the x.group() returns isn't ,then the result of print(neg_handled) will be another one.Actually,the result of print(neg)handled) is "I is not a ads"So,how to explain this and how can I know the 1st parenthesized group refers to "isn't" or "is not"?

Comment: And I still want to ask what does x implies in my program.

Comment: I have completed my answer. The 1st parenthesized group is retrieved after matching the regex with the string `I isn't a sds`, so of course it is `isn't`. It is then substituted with `is not` into `neg_handled` thanks to the `sub` method (and the lambda function).

Comment: @LiuQiang8650 Have you finally understood ? Is my answer sufficient or not for you ?

Comment: I am so sorry that I have not access to Stack overflow these days because my access to ipV6 is invalid.Your complete answer is very helpful.Thank you so much.I will vote for your answer